# How to close a QDialog at click outside and close at click a sub-widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qdialog

I have a little problem. I'm trying close a QDialog when I press a QPushButton(child) or at click outside of the QDialog.
I dont want close with connect in the function of the button. I want close when the QDialog detect a child clicked.

Sry my english.

thanks a lot.

Dialog.py

```
# coding=utf-8
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class SimpleDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, title=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Tool)
        self.setMinimumWidth(280)

        self.__inWidget = []
        self.__textColor = "#212121"

        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto Medium")
        font.setPixelSize(20)

        self.__title = QLabel()
        self.__title.setFont(font)
        self.__title.setWordWrap(True)
        self.__title.hide()
        if title:
            self.setTitle(title)

        self.__vLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        textLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        textLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        textLayout.addWidget(self.__title)

        contentLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        contentLayout.addLayout(textLayout)
        contentLayout.addLayout(self.__vLayout)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(contentLayout)

        main = QVBoxLayout()
        main.addWidget(widget)

        backBoard = QHBoxLayout()
        backBoard.addLayout(main)
        self.setLayout(backBoard)

    def focusOutEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.close()

    def addItem(self, simpleDialogItem):
        """ SimpleDialog.addItem(SimpleDialogItem)
        Agrega un item al SimpleDialog
        """
        if type(simpleDialogItem) == SimpleDialogItem:
            self.__vLayout.addWidget(simpleDialogItem)
            self.__inWidget.append(simpleDialogItem)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Se espera un SimpleDialogItem y se recibio: " + type(simpleDialogItem))

    def setTitle(self, title):
        """ SimpleDialog.setTitle(str)
        Establece el titulo del SimpleDialog
        """
        self.__title.setText(title)
        self.__title.show()


class SimpleDialogItem(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, icon=None, text=None):
        """ SimpleDialogItem(icon=path, text=str)
        Item utilizado en SimpleDialog
        """
        QPushButton.__init__(self)

        self.__text = QLabel()
        self.__text.setWordWrap(True)

        self.__layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.__layout.addWidget(self.__text)
        self.setFixedHeight(48)

        self.setLayout(self.__layout)
        if text:
            self.setText(text)

    def setText(self, text):
        """ SimpleDialogItem.setText(str)
        Establece el texto del widget
        """
        self.__text.setText(text)
```

test.py

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPushButton, QDialog

from Dialog import SimpleDialog, SimpleDialogItem



class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        b = QPushButton("button")
        b.released.connect(self.hola)

        l = QHBoxLayout()
        l.addWidget(b)

        self.addView(l)

    def hola(self):
        t = "Three line wrapped text goes here making it wrap to next line and continues longer to be here "
        tt = "You'll lose all photos and media."
        ttt = "You'll lose all photos and media."
        sd = SimpleDialog(title="Are you sure?")
        self.item = SimpleDialogItem(text=t, icon="slide_1.jpg")
        self.item.released.connect(self.chao)
        item2 = SimpleDialogItem(text=tt)
        item3 = SimpleDialogItem(text=ttt)
        sd.addItem(self.item)
        sd.addItem(item2)
        sd.addItem(item3)
        sd.exec_()

    def chao(self):
        print "Hola mundo!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.activateWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code, no detect focusOut in SimpleDialog :( Any solution?

Comment: I try user Qt.Popup how windowFlat but draw a shadow in the window.

Comment: You could place only the most important part of your code.

Comment: what's MainLayout??

Comment: If you speak Spanish better post it on http://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: The MainLayout is a QWidget modified :)
In the test I use a SimpleDialog and add 3 SimpleDialogItem, I want close the SimpleDialog when I press on Item added. 
I ask my question in "ES" forum too, but here I can find more entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to show you the solution that I found to my problem.
First, how do I close my widget SimpleDialogal click away from it?
I made a small modification at the end of the widget, which allows me to expand this one and manage its entire area.

```
main = QVBoxLayout()
main.addWidget(...contenido...)

self.fullWidget = QWidget()
self.fullWidget.setLayout(main)
self.fullWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: RGB(0,0,0,30)")

l = QHBoxLayout()
l.addWidget(self.fullWidget)

self.showFullScreen()
self.setLayout(l)
```

So, this way I can write the `mouseReleaseEvent` to detect the top area and when the *click* is closed.

```
def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QEvent):
    if QApplication.widgetAt(QEvent.pos()) == self.fullWidget:
        self.close()
```

Now as a solution to the problem of closing `SimpleDialog` when pressing the `SimpleDialogItem` is about writing the `mouseReleaseEvent` method to with QApplication find the parent and close it

```
def mouseReleaseEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for widget in QApplication.topLevelWidgets():
        if type(widget) == SimpleDialog:
            widget.close()
```